# Build Multiple Projects in a Single Solution for VSTS

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, tfsbuild, release-management

I'm in this case, I have a single solution built on Visual Studio 2013. It contains more than 10 projects that reference each others, I need only to build and release 3 projects of them on Azure via Visual Studio Team Services so the question is what is the best approach to do this

Thank you

Comment: Do you solve this issue with our solution?

Answer (score 0):

If they all reference each other than you may need to build all of them. Dependencies will be resolved at build time.

You can reference individual Project files in place of a Solution. You will then need to maintain order yourself.

Just use the same build step for building a Solution, but fill out a Project (.proj) file instead. Control the order by having multiple build steps.

Comment: For the second alternative how can I do that, I mean which build step type could I use to build each project a side all this being said, how to also take consideration of the projet dependencies in this case, I assume that it is not enough to only maintain the order. Could you please propose a walkthough in clear steps thank you MrHinsh

Comment: I updates old the answer. You use the same build step.

Answer (score -1):

Please read my Suggestions below-
- Copy all the references dll's in one shared folder through Post build event.
- Create new solution according to your deployment needs and take all references from the shared folder in all projects.
- Deploy the solution you want

Answer (score -1):

If the references are [project references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx), you just need to specify the solution file (.sln) to build, otherwise, you need to specify project dependence (Right click your solution=> Project Dependence=>Select a project=>Check the projects’ options that dependence to)
[image]

Comment: Stars in, this is not an answer o the question asked. This is about Team Build!